# how to keep theme background image, menu or site header image while moving site in sub directory?

Tags: menus, themes, theme-twenty-ten

I'm moving site root to sub directory, menu background image or site header display as default,
I have change URL in db as set all sub directory location also set .htaccess
but my custom background or header and menu not display as before?
I'm used twenty ten theme.

Comment: Multi-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13987678/1287812 ... Please, check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106323/185667

Answer (score 0):

The settings for themes is in a array, serialized data in the database. It is not easy to change this inside the database. See for the `options` Table and search for the entry `theme_mods_twentyten`.

Comment: hey, inside theme_mods_twentyten array Imagepath correct for image

Comment: Then it is right; maybe cache problem?